# Aggregate by date and item count

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I'm trying to do something that I think would be simple, but it's proving to not be. I have data in a CSV in the following format:

```
document_id, change_id, change_author, doc_author, date
aaaaaaa, a1, joe, jessie, 3/15/17
aaaaaaa, a2, jane, jessie, 1/2/17
bbbbbbb, a1, jane, jack, 4/5/17
```

I want to produce something like the following:

```
Author   17-01   17-02   17-03   17-04     # this is the header row
Joe         12       8      15       2     # Count for joe
Jane        17      15      22      10
```

The desired result is the count of annotations done by an author in any given month, regardless which document the annotation was made to.

I'm running into newb brick walls everywhere including only seeing how to create a data.frame with named rows instead of named columns. I can get a list of authors and list of dates, but I can't seem to produce the aggregate I want. My code so far is:

```
case_stats <- read.table("~/Downloads/Annotations.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
case_stats <- cbind(case_stats, Month = format(as.Date(case_stats$date_antn, "%m/%d/%y"), "%y-%m"))
months <- unique(subset(case_stats, select = c(Month)))
authors <- unique(subset(case_stats, select = c(author)))
count <- length(unlist(months))
df <- data.frame(num = rep(NA, count), txt=rep("", count), stringsAsFactors=FALSE, col.names = c(months))
```

Comment: Can you clarify your sample data and desired behavior? It's not clear how the three example lines  you've given would become the two lines in the result. For example, where are the integers coming from?

Comment: Updated to clarify. Sorry about the lack of clarity. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling your data `dd`, we can use the `reshape2::dcast` function to convert it from long to wide with this aggregation. If your data is large, you should make it a `data.table` and use `data.table::dcast` instead.

```
dd$month = lubridate::floor_date(as.Date(dd$date, "%m/%d/%y"), unit = "month")
reshape2::dcast(dd, change_author ~ month, value.var = "month", fun.aggregate = length)
#   change_author 2017-01-01 2017-03-01 2017-04-01
# 1          jane          1          0          1
# 2           joe          0          1          0
```

---

Using this input:

```
dd = read.table(text = "document_id, change_id, change_author, doc_author, date
aaaaaaa, a1, joe, jessie, 3/15/17
aaaaaaa, a2, jane, jessie, 1/2/17
bbbbbbb, a1, jane, jack, 4/5/17", sep = ",", header = T)
```